# IPA Server setup failing on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, installation, ldap, ipa

When I try to install/configure IPA Server on CentOS 6.6, I see the following error message

> [root@machine1 ~]# ipa-server-install --setup-dns
>
> "Must be root to set up server"

Installation went fine with out an issue but when I try to configure using the above command I see "Must be root to set up server"

Comment: Run `id root` command and make sure root has `0` uid, if it is not `0` then it failed

Answer (score 0):

If you open `ipa-server-install` script, it is written in `python` and you will find following snippet in that script, If root uid isn't `0` then print "Must be root to set up server"

```
if os.getegid() != 0:
           sys.exit("Must be root to set up server")
```

Make sure you are root and your root uid `0`

```
[root@ipa ~]# whoami
root
[root@ipa ~]# id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Here is what I see after I logged into CentOS server     


[root@machine1 ~]# whoami
root
[root@machine1 ~]# id root
uid=0(root) gid=500(hadoop) groups=500(hadoop)
[root@machine1 ~]#

Comment: i commented out the if condition in the ipa-server-install file and ran the setup again.

Comment: looks like it is working but not sure if that is the right way to do

Comment: for a while i thought it was working but now i ran into few more setup issues, so it is not a good idea to comment out the "if" condition in the ipa-server-install file. 

Still looking for help from the experts ..

Comment: Why your root user `gid` is `500`? I would say please change root user `gid` to `0` just like i showed you on my answer section. I don't know what hadoop doing with root user? something is massed up in your system with uid/gid of group.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get pass this error and install IPA Server. However I ran into issues with the IPA client installtion on another node with in the same network.

Comment: [root@dravidian1 ~]# ipa-client-install --domain=hashmap.com --server=ldap.hashmap.com --realm=HASHMAP.COM -p admin@hashmap.com  --password=hortonworks --mkhomedir --hostname=dravidian1.hashmap.com

Comment: Failed to verify that ldap.hashmap.com is an IPA Server.
This may mean that the remote server is not up or is not reachable due to network or firewall settings.
Please make sure the following ports are opened in the firewall settings:
     TCP: 80, 88, 389
     UDP: 88 (at least one of TCP/UDP ports 88 has to be open)
Also note that following ports are necessary for ipa-client working properly after enrollment:
     TCP: 464
     UDP: 464, 123 (if NTP enabled)
Installation failed. Rolling back changes.
IPA client is not configured on this system.

Comment: I checked my firewall settings .. and they are not currently running

Comment: all the ports are wide open

Comment: how did you check ports are open? you can use `telnet <ipaddress> <port>` to see it is really connecting to remote server. make sure `SElinux` is disable